# CoreBluetooth: didDisconnectPeripheral callback while in CBPeripheralStateConnecting

Tags: ios7, core-bluetooth

Going through the logs generated by my 'CoreBluetooth' state machine and have noticed on occasions a `didDisconnectPeripheral` is being called while the peripheral is in `CBPeripheralStateConnecting` and before a `didConnectPeripheral`. The code is immune to this strangeness however I would like to understand what is happening.

Anyone else experienced this or anything similar? I cannot find any logical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS6 when CoreBluetooth was rather less mature I adopted the connection strategy of  requesting a connection, if connection didn't result in the next 2 seconds, I would then call `cancelPeripheralConnection` and then issue another `connectPeripheral` this cycle would continue 3 further times before terminating and informing the user that something is wrong.

It would appear that the calls to `didDisconnectPeripheral`, even when not first connected, were a result of the intermediate calls to `cancelPeripheralConnection`.

Now with the stability of iOS7 and having learned that `connectPeripheral` never times out I have removed the complexity of intermediate `cancelPeripheralConnection` & `connectPeripheral` calls and just wait for the connection, with a timeout.

No more mystery `didDisconnectPeripheral` calls!